# Open specific ViewController from push notification when application closed

Tags: ios, swift

I wan't to open special ViewController when push notification when app is closed (not in background or inactive)
When app in background it's work , but when app is closed Xcode push to Main ViewController

I try to use all of application states , but doesn't work

```
    if(application.applicationState == .background) {
        let dict = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
        if let cont = dict {
            let cate = cont["category"] as? String
            if let category = cate {
                switch category {
                case "NEWS":
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Shops", bundle: nil)
                    let NewBoard = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainShopsViewController")
                    let tabbar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController

                    let navcontrol = tabbar?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
                    tabbar?.selectedIndex = 1
                    navcontrol?.pushViewController(NewBoard, animated: true)
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open `vc` from the closed state of your app, you can check if app was opened from click on Notification in this method of `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

It looks like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // When the app launch after user tap on notification (originally was not running / not in background)
        if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {

            goToEventDetails(userInfo: launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any])

        }
    }
```

Where `goToEventDetails` is method which instantiates VC and pushed id, and `[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any]` is content of Notification.

Comment: can you explain last part of code ? where goToEventdetails

Comment: instead of this method you should instantiate your view controller and show it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to do that ..

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // tell the app that we have finished processing the user’s action / response
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: but want when app is closed , is it real ?

Comment: this function will work if the app in the background or closed, the function get called if the application received a notification.

Comment: No, this function will not be called from a killed app

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
   if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any] {

        }

  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = yourViewController
  completionHandler()
}
```